# Append folder path to string name

Tags: python

I have several image names in my directory that I want to read.

```
sq_of_images = listdir('images/sequence1/')  
sq_of_images = [img for img in sq_of_images if img.endswith(".jpg")]
print(sq_of_images)
```

> ['im_001.jpg', 'im_002.jpg', 'im_003.jpg', 'im_004.jpg', 'im_005.jpg',
>   'im_006.jpg', 'im_007.jpg', 'im_008.jpg', 'im_009.jpg', 'im_010.jpg',
>   'im_011.jpg', 'im_012.jpg', 'im_013.jpg', 'im_014.jpg', 'im_015.jpg',
>   'im_016.jpg', 'im_017.jpg', 'im_018.jpg', 'im_019.jpg', 'im_020.jpg',
>   'im_021.jpg', 'im_022.jpg', 'im_023.jpg', 'im_024.jpg', 'im_025.jpg',
>   'im_026.jpg', 'im_027.jpg', 'im_028.jpg', 'im_029.jpg', 'im_030.jpg']
>       30

I'd like to append the folder path to the images as well but can't figure out how to do it. Typing it this way gives me an error.

```
sq_of_images = ['images/', img for img in sq_of_images if img.endswith(".jpg")]
```

Comment: try `'images/' + img` to concatenate strings

Comment: @NicoAlbers thank you. going from matlab to python takes a while getting used to

Comment: Yeah, I know that experience.. it's hard but you will like it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate strings using plus sign instead of comma:

```
sq_of_images = ['images/' + img for img in sq_of_images if img.endswith(".jpg")]
```

You also can insert multiple fields into a string using `format`:

```
sq_of_images = [
    '{img_folder}/{img_name}'.format(img_folder='images', img_name=img) 
    for img in sq_of_images if img.endswith(".jpg")]
```

Of course you can also use the join function like Reut Sharabani proposed in his answer, I really like that approach more than operating with string methods because it is more robust.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can use simple string concatenation `'images/' + img`, there is an `os` submodule for handling paths which is called `path`. You can use `os.path.join` to join paths:

```
from os import path
sq_of_images = [path.join('images/', img) for img in sq_of_images if img.endswith(".jpg")]
```